# Fragment layout not covering entire screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I was trying to have a map displayed on one of the fragments of the Bottom Navigation.

But, attached fragment is not covering complete screen. i tried adding background color to the fragment is as below:

[image]

While trying to add a map to the fragment it also is not convering the complete screen instead it shows only a bit of the screen.
Below my layout code:

Bottom Navigation.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_5">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        layout="@layout/include_card_view_search_bar" />


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollingCache="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_middle" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/blue_500"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>




    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/blue_grey_700"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state_white_2"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/color_state_white_2"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation_shifting" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Map Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_soft" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/map_button"
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:onClick="clickAction"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_near_me" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Map"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/list_button"
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:onClick="clickAction"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="List"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickAction"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/deep_orange_400"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Attaching the Map using my code:

```
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

The app looks like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add  android:fillViewport="true" in NestedScrollView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_5">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        layout="@layout/include_card_view_search_bar" />


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_middle" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/blue_500"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/blue_grey_700"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state_white_2"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/color_state_white_2"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation_shifting" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was having same issue, ScrollView was wrapping content from Fragment. `android:fillViewport="true"` did what I need

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If NestedScrollView is not necessary try using some other ViewGroup i.e LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in its place. It seems the issue is in wrapping fragment content inside NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken FrameLayout(id-content) inside NestedScrollView, try removing NestedScrollView from there and adding it to the layout by which you are replacing it with FrameLayout(id-content)

Comment: I need the Nested scroll view, as i am using OnScrollChangeListener and hiding the Toolbar and bottom navigation bar